# AutoFill for WinForm, where data is pasted from an Excel row- Last row keeps getting skipped

Tags: c#, winforms, copy-paste, autofill

I tried my best to find a better way to copy a data row from excel, and have the user paste it directly in the `Form` by a click of a button. The following function can be called from any suitable event. This code is the best that I was able to assemble using various methods I found across the website, but this code skips the last entry of the row.

Can someone help me out to get the code working properly? Any suggestions to do it differently are most welcome as I am just a beginner.

Also, I could not get the date to parse properly, that's the reason I commented that part out in the if condition for `DateTimePicker`.

UPDATE: I was able to figure out why the last entry of the row was getting skipped. There was no "\t" at the end of the string due to copy-paste format. I've corrected that code below. Still struggling with the date format to parse though.

```
private void autofill()
    {
        DataObject o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        if (o.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        {
            string[] pastedRows = Regex.Split(o.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().TrimEnd("\r\n".ToCharArray()), "\r\n");

            var cell = "";
            int i = 1;

            if (pastedRows[pastedRows.Length - 1] != "\t")
            {
                pastedRows[pastedRows.Length - 1] += "\t";
            }

            foreach (string pastedRow in pastedRows)
            {
                foreach (char str in pastedRow)
                {
                    if (str.ToString() != "\t")
                    {
                        cell = cell + str.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (Control c in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
                        {
                            if (c.TabStop == true && c.TabIndex == i)
                            {
                                if (c is TextBox)
                                {
                                    ((TextBox)c).Text = cell.ToString();
                                    continue;
                                }
                                else if (c is ComboBox)
                                {
                                    ((ComboBox)c).Text = cell.ToString();
                                    continue;
                                }
                                else if (c is DateTimePicker)
                                {
                                    //((DateTimePicker)c).Value = DateTime.Parse(cell.ToString());
                                    continue;
                                }
                                else if (c is RichTextBox)
                                {
                                    ((RichTextBox)c).Text = cell.ToString();
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        cell = "";
                        i = i + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, you should probably ask this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thankx Mitch. I'm still getting used to this. I'll take the question there.

Comment: Hey guys, Code Review is for fully working code, and you state that you have a bug related to the last line, and have commented out a part related to a bug when parsing dates. Please do read a [Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: In which case, I'm at the right place to get help. The guide to Code review was really helpful. Thankx for the help, holroy.